# CakePHP 2 TimeFormat

Tags: php, cakephp, datetime, timezone, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem with time format I have a code like this

```
        //in the core file it set to UTC
        debug(date_default_timezone_get());
        $currentTime = time(); //UTC

        //CurrentTime in UTC
        debug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$currentTime));

        $timepst = CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $currentTime, null, 'PST');
        $timejst = CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $currentTime, null, 'JST');

        //I'm trying to convert back the time from PST to UTC using PST time
        $timeutc = CakeTime::format('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($timepst), null, 'UTC');

        debug('PST : ' . $timepst);
        debug('JST : ' . $timejst);
        debug('UTC : ' . $timeutc);
```

The result of that is

```
'UTC'

'2012-10-05 19:44:50'

'PST : 2012-10-05 12:44:50'

'JST : 2012-10-06 04:44:50'

'UTC : 2012-10-05 12:44:50'
```

My question is, how come using PST Time to convert back to UTC does not work?
Any Help?

Basicly, I want to let user to save something say article, based on their own timezone (for date input), but I need to convert it back to UTC to save it in database.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is done based on time difference between your server's timezone and user timezone passed as param to CakeTime::format(). In your example code in your 3rd call to CakeTime::format() you pass user timezone as UTC and server's timezone is also UTC hence there will be no change in time.

Comment: is there any way to pass the user timezone as the timezone that is set? and not as UTC (frm the 3rd call).

Comment: I don't understand your question. Since the time you are passing in 3rd call is for PST timezone you have to set server's timezone to PST to get the result you expect.